# Did plane crasher Andreas Lubitz look for gay porn?

Tags: germany

[Breitbart reported in 2015](http://www.breitbart.com/national-security/2015/03/30/report-germanwings-co-pilot-surfed-gay-porn-and-suicide-websites-before-crash/):

> The picture of Germanwings co-pilot Andreas Lubitz’ troubled state of mind grows more complex with the revelation, reported by International Business Times, that investigators have discovered that Lubitz “trawled the dark side of the web visiting, among other things, sites containing gay porn, suicide themes and sexual perversions.”

However, it also reported that the evidence was suspect:

> It should be noted that International Business Times appears to be the only English-language source for the information about Lubitz’ web-surfing history, at the time of this writing; other references to the matter all seem to link back to IBT and its source in the Dusseldorf police. As of Monday morning, most other reports seemed confident that Lubitz’ diary had not been found yet. Reports on the co-pilot’s background have been tricky to follow because, outside of major public press conferences from French and German officials, media in the U.S. and Britain are generally relaying translated reports from German publications, which seem to have a variety of different off-the-record sources in various law-enforcement entities.

Comment: Google gives 0 sources for this from German media. The [IBT article](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/germanwings-alps-disaster-co-pilot-andreas-lubitz-trawled-suicide-gay-websites-before-crash-1494044) claims "Lubitz was given the nickname "Tomato Andy": a German term for repressed homosexuals." As a German, I've never heard of this term, and the magazine Focus [reports](http://www.focus.de/panorama/welt/lebenskrise-als-moegliches-motiv-wieso-flog-andreas-l-die-maschine-gegen-den-berg_id_4574082.html) this nickname comes from his time as a flight attendant, which makes the IBT article dubious to me.